# functions.php pharse error on complete new install

Tags: functions, errors, parse

So I have just installed wordpress on shared hosting (with php 8.0 & DB (I forgot what version but it works) and immediately after setup, I get this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/wwwroot/hkc01210429205315/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1090
```

So like what is going on?
This seems to only happen some of the times that I visit the site (7/10) and other times it shows up just fine. Like, WTF?

Here is functions.php line 1090:

function add_query_arg( ... $args ) {

heres a link to the entire file:
https://apipixel-1302080057.cos.ap-hongkong.myqcloud.com/functions.php

Sry for my terrible post, I'm a first time WP user :(

Comment: You would only get this error if you were running a PHP version below 5.6. You need to speak to your host.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I ran a php version checker, here is the results: http://txti.es/rgya6. So it seems to be on 8.0?

Comment: @day_cat: change this line to: `function add_query_arg( $args ) {` and you should be fine.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz Under no circumstances should they edit core WordPress functions.

Comment: @day_cat Regardless, you need to speak to your host. This error can only be caused by running an old PHP version. Only your host is going to be able to help you figure out why that's happening some times.

Comment: @JacobPeattie: you are 100% right! My mistake. I didn't notice that this file is in `wp-includes`